# I want to get all products and category name of each product from category table - Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to get all products and get each product category name from the category table .. anyone can help ???

```
  public function viewProducts(Request $request){

 $products = Product::get();

 foreach($products as $key => $val){
  $category_name = Category::where(['id' => $val- >category_id])->first();
  $products[$key]->category_name = $category_name->name;
 }
 $products = json_decode(json_encode($products));
 //echo "<pre>"; print_r($products); die;
   return view('admin.products.view_products')->with(compact('products'));
}
```

Comment: You can create relationships in laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use join

```
$products = Product::join('categories','categories.id', 'products.category_id')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, Gaurav ... but garauv i want also get stock on my another "products attribute " table so how can i get can you guide ??

Comment: Do you have product id on stocks table ?

Comment: $products = Product::join('categories','categories.id', 'products.category_id')->join('stocks','stocks.product_id','products.id')->get();

Comment: Can you show me send products_attributes table structure ?

Comment: Yes sure go ahead

Comment: how can i send you image ??